# How to add mime type in web sphere liberty server?

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

How to add **Mime type** in web sphere liberty server. we are new to web sphere liberty server.

Comment: You may find this resource usefull: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYGQH_4.5.0/admin/admin/t_admin_files_config_mime.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so we both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add new extensions and their corresponding mimetypes by appending the a section like the following to server.xml:

```
<mimeTypes>
    <type>.bar=text/bar</type>
</mimeTypes>
```

I didn't have any luck overriding a built-in type this way.

Comment: i have set the  Mime type in server.xml file  it is working fine, Thank you very much for your help.            
        <mimeTypes>
  <type>.htc=text/x-component</type>
 </mimeTypes>